# How to set an image to fill in full view?

Tags: iphone, cgbitmapcontextcreate

i am using below code for fill rgba forful view. but i am getting half(1/2) width only. anybody please inform me anything wrong with my code.

```
             CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
             rgba,
             width,     // width = 320
             height,        // 460
             8               //CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),    
             4 * width, // rowbytes
             colorSpace,
             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
             );
```

Comment: you mean your main view with 320x460 px

Comment: hi neo ya my screen width is 320X460 i am getting 160X460

Answer (score 0):

Try using:`width * [UIDevice currentDevice].scale` instead of `width` and `height * [UIDevice currentDevice].scale` instead of `height`.

Remember that your device can have a Retina screen and your 320px view is in fact a 640px view. (scale = 2)

Comment: How about scaling your Core Graphics context with CGContextScaleCTM? Have you tested this in retina and non-retina?